# Can't bind UDP socket but port is free

Tags: linux, bind, port, udp, netstat

I've been struggling for a while now with this so maybe someone here is able to help me.
I'm setting up a [CS:GO server](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers) that's going to be running on port `27059`.
*(This is a copy&paste from a working server, so I'm not posting config files used)*

When I try to start it, I get this error:

`WARNING: UDP_OpenSocket: unable to bind socket`

Which basically means that the port is already being used, so I do the following:

`Stop the server`
`netstat -punta | grep  \.27059   # I get nothing`
`Start the server`
`netstat -punta | grep  \.27059`

And get:

```
tcp        0      0  192.0.2.178:27059     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21932/./srcds_linux
udp        0      0  192.0.2.178:27059     0.0.0.0:*                           21932/./srcds_linux
```

So it looks like the server is actually being able to use that port but, somehow, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Well, I'am not an linux expert, but it's a warning, not a error. thus the server work I guess anyhow ?

Comment: Just seen it's for counter-strike, your question will fall offtopic there, unless it's to run your business

Comment: No, it does not work. And, even though it's about administrating a game, it's also about network administration and yes, it's my business

Comment: I had to ask, but as the socket is open, does it need another port that got blocked ?

Comment: It does need another port for `hltv` but, for testing reasons, I've dissabled it (it's not needed for the server to run).

Comment: with another port it start or not ? -port 270xx I seen there is a limit of how much instance can run on a server.

Comment: I tried with many different ports, none of them working. And haven't read anything about limitations so far.

Comment: did you used +ip ? as it show up as 0.0.0.0